# Художественное редактирование предложения с добавлением контекста

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, грамматика

Предложение с другого форума: «***Поскольку помещение оружейной кладовой изначально затемнено, оказывается, что в комнате помимо нас находится неизвестное третье лицо подслушивающее разговор***».

Автор просил проверить запятые, меня же удивили ответы: (1) Все четко! А надо поправить? (2) Предложено обособить причастный оборот и оборот «помимо нас».

Мне же кажется, что у этого предложения более серьезные проблемы. Откуда оно только взялось, кто так пишет!  Какая-то **малохудожественная книжная речь сомнительной структуры**, вялая и безжизненная. А чему удивляться, если на уроках русского языка только правила учат и тесты решают (учат, учат, да никак не выучат). В результате лет через пятьдесят все так и будут писать.

И это не говоря уж о прочих ошибках. Оборот «помимо нас» совершенно не на месте, и нужно ли его обособлять (только не по правилам, а по структуре, при факультативном обособлении)? Время действия выглядит  несогласованным.

А как бы вы его отредактировали?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В оригинале время неудачно согласовано, поэтому  хотелось бы рассмотреть  два варианта:  (1) автор описывает события, происходящие в прошлом; (1) автор описывает события, происходящие сейчас (стиль художественный).

Я написала для себя два этих варианта, добавив одно-два предложения (чтобы время происходящего  и ситуация были ясными). Туда же включила исходное предложение, стараясь следовать  семантике и отчасти сохранив лексику. Грамматику меняла, как мне нравится.

Мне хотелось бы сравнить свой текст с тем, который напишут другие (один или два  варианта по желанию). Вопрос конкурсный. **Побудьте просто писателем,** а оценивать вас будут критики, а не вы сами. Анализом можно заняться после.

Если задание кажется сложным, то опишите просто **похожий эпизод**, сохранив место действия и элементы сюжета. Очень интересен вариант, когда событие **изображается в текущее время**. Мне он показался более трудным, поэтому хотелось бы увидеть и его.

**ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ГОЛОСУЙТЕ ЗА УЧАСТНИКОВ!** А то я не узнаю, кто вам больше нравится.

**Конкурс закончен, до новых конкурсов!**:)

Я благодарю всех участников. Хороших ответов было много  –  жаль, что для одного вопроса  предусмотрена только одна награда.

Кратко объясню свой выбор. **Ответ oleedd**  наиболее близок теме вопроса, для меня же там особенно интересно  изображение  **текущих событий.**

Автор-рассказчик напоминает мне **комментатора**, который  на ходу дает нам пояснения и одновременно сам участвует в событиях.  Вот он услышал звук, а дальше описания прерываются его мыслями.  Такие переходы очень интересны!

Comment: Умеете Вы, _Sharon_, озадачить.

Comment: Текст в студию! ))))

Comment: Римма, а что делать, надо же вас как-то «развеселить». Может, напишете что-нибудь? Я подозреваю у вас талант писателя – так мне однажды понравилась  ваша коротенькая заметка о природе  (помните, когда я спрашивала о сороках). Правда, здесь  другой  жанр (повествовательный), но вы ведь вообще к литературе очень неравнодушны.

Comment: Серж, по вашей просьбе  текст в студии.

Answer (score 2):

1. Прежде всего вопиет порочная причинно-следственная связь: буквально, по причине затемнения в помещении находился человек - как будто темнота притягивает людей и потому кто-то с высокой вероятностью должен был там найтись.
2. Что такое "изначально затемнено" в настоящем времени? Оно *навеки* затемнено с каким-то умыслом, для защиты от света документов или акварелей? Меньше вопросов вызвало бы "изначально *было* затемнено", если позже мы включили свет или фонарик (тогда лучше "поначалу"). Это как минимум стилистический просчёт.
3. Перегружены вариантами ссылки на кладовую, которая то "помещение", то "комната".
4. Излишен "обвинительный уклон" по отношению к неизвестному: "подслушивают" обычно с умыслом, а человек, судя по контексту, случайно находился там, куда пришли герои.

Вариант исправления:

> Поскольку в оружейной кладовой было темно, мы не сразу заметили, что
> там находится посторонний, который мог слышать начало нашего
> разговора.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander, критика отличная!  Всё в точку.  Теперь я лучше понимаю, почему это предложение мне так не понравилось. Вариант текста тоже правильный, но немного затянутый. Хотелось бы больше экспрессии, более высокий темп.  (Это я сравниваю со своим вариантом, который я тоже написала).

Comment: Оруже́йная (или оружейная **комната**, оружейная **кладовая**) — **помещение**... https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Оружейня

Comment: Да, комнату надо бы убрать, без нее лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Я приведу свои  варианты, но только  для того, чтобы была понятна задача  о правильном обозначении времени, когда происходит событие.

**Это отнюдь не образец**, а черновой набросок. Например, текст у @Егор Сальков  мне понравился (пока дан в комментариях), хотя  он выглядит совсем по-другому.   Также очень хорош критический разбор у @Alex_ander, эту работу тоже можно считать конкурсной.  Да и вообще любые фантазии только приветствуются – как говорится, "все жанры хороши, кроме скучного". Хорошо бы получить хотя  бы три-четыре варианта, тогда конкурс обязательно состоится.

**Мои варианты**

Оригинал (исходный текст):  «*Поскольку помещение оружейной кладовой изначально затемнено, оказывается, что в комнате помимо нас находится неизвестное третье лицо подслушивающее разговор*».  Вероятно, это рассказ о действии, происходящем в текущий момент.

(1) Действие происходит в текущий момент

Вдруг что-то  зашуршало, потом загремело.  Кажется, скрипнула дверь.  Кто-то прятался  за стеллажами  и теперь вышел?  ***В оружейной кладовой темно – мы могли и не заметить неизвестного, и тогда он слышал наш  разговор.***

(2) Рассказ о событии, которое уже произошло

Мы услышали шорох,  что-то загремело, потом  тихонько скрипнула дверь. ***В оружейной кладовой было темно, и мы не сразу заметили неизвестного, который слышал  наш разговор.*** Он прятался  за стеллажами  и выдал себя неосторожным движением.

Comment: Пока эта лучшая правка, что я видел. Без воды. Текст должен бы таким, чтобы его можно было легко читать. Именно как у вас. Мой голос — вам.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж!  Знаете, я впервые задумалась о том, как люди пишут художественные повествовательные тексты, выдерживая нужный стиль. Мне это показалось трудным, пришлось думать над  тремя предложениями.  А в моем тексте (1) вроде бы используется несобственная прямая речь –  там повествование ведется от первого лица как автора, но оно прерывается мыслями  персонажа, который участвует в действии.  Это мне показалось  удивительным. Стала смотреть другие книги – там несобственная прямая речь на каждом шагу.

Comment: Безусловно, вы правы! Писать повествовательные тексты — непросто.

Answer (score 2):

Пришло в голову, как описать от лица персонажа, а не автора, уж простите.

В прошлом:

*— Сидим мы, значит, с приятелем и вдруг раздаётся страшный грохот! Как будто сто слонов по́д пол разом провалились! **А в оружейной кладовой-то темно, видимо, кто-то проник туда и мог услышать наш разговор.** А потом, когда пытался выйти, пошёл впотьмах не туда, наткнулся на грабли и в падении задел ведро, а остальные так и посыпались. Вот только появления его мы не слышали, так заговорились! Интересно, что же ему тут понадобилось?! И кто меня дёрнул за язык про своё богатство рассказывать!*

Добавил две фразы. Предпоследнюю, чтобы показать, что цели подслушать собеседников вполне могло и не быть, а была либо другая цель (может быть, ограбить), либо, например, праздное любопытство.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем,  очень интересно!   Какие у вас впечатления от творческого процесса?  Вам раньше приходилось быть сочинителем?

Comment: Спасибо за задание, Шарон!)) Не знаю, может быть, только когда пытался кому-то что-то покрасочнее рассказать.)) А вам приходилось?

Comment: Разную мелочь (стихи, сказки, пьески), а вот в части художественного повествование - это мой дебют. Было очень трудно :)

Answer (score 2):

Мы находились в том крыле, куда еще не добрались ни туристы, ни цивилизация; мы спорили. Спорили долго и — безрезультатно.
Я сновал по каменному коридору, который освещался единственным узким окном, размахивал руками и говорил, говорил. А хозяин замка, прислонившись к окованной створе, только иногда вставлял пару слов и то ли хмурился, то ли улыбался (кто их разберет, этих аристократов?).
— Я устал от твоей беготни. Зайдем, — сказал он и кивнул в темноту оружейной.
Неожиданно почти абсолютную тишину нарушил громкий хруст (так мы не одни!), затем что-то скрежетнуло и лязгнуло.
— Арбалет... — Голос был невозмутим. — Нас, молодой человек, подслушивали.

Comment: Римма, отличный вариант!  Я в вас не ошиблась, когда читала ваши описания природы – в детективном повествовании вы не менее хороши.  Интрига захватывающая…

Comment: Спасибо за добрые слова.

Answer (score 1):

Не всё верно. Логическая ошибка, неподходящее слово. Ну и нужна запятая перед "подслушивающее".
То, что помещение затемнено, совсем не означает (не факт, что так **окажется**), что там находится неизвестное третье лицо, но так **может оказаться**.

Желательно так:
*Можно предположить, что в комнате помимо нас находится неизвестное третье лицо, подслушивающее разговор, поскольку помещение оружейной кладовой затемнено.* "Изначально" не очень к месту. Это разговорный вариант, который означает "с начала происходящего", а не со времён постройки комнаты (с самого времени создания), например:
*Оно изначально так было (сломано), я ничего не трогал.* || Но не изготовлено поломанным. Не всё время так было, хотя "изначально" намекает на обратное и в словарях указано лишь такое значение.

Больше сохранён оригинал:
*Раз помещение оружейной кладовой затемнено, то может оказаться, что в комнате помимо нас находится неизвестное третье лицо, подслушивающее разговор.*

*Помимо нас* — вдобавок к нам. Запятая не требуется. Думаю, что оно совершенно на месте. Логическое ударение на него не падает при обычном раскладе, но может падать при желании автора (при обособлении).

Если всё-таки оказалось, то так можно исправить логику:
*Из-за того, что помещение оружейной кладовой затемнено, оказалось так, что в комнате помимо нас находится неизвестное третье лицо, подслушивающее разговор.* || Стилистика не лучшая, но с логикой порядок.

Художественные варианты:
*Ой-ой, мне что-то послышалось, у меня нехорошее предчувствие. Здесь темно — может, за нами кто-то наблюдает?

Из-за того, что в оружейной было темно, мы не заметили шпиона, который подслушивал наш разговор.

Ты что здесь делаешь? Мы не заметили его, потому что здесь темно. Может, он подслушивал?*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Логика у вас, возможно, неплохая, но не для писателя.  Как вы думаете, что там произошло? Вероятно, послышался шорох – так неизвестный обнаружил себя. Собеседники испуганы?  Или  они спокойны, но напряжены?  Действие происходит здесь и сейчас, а этого нет ни в оригинале, ни у вас.  С одним конкурсом у меня не получается, может, другой попробовать – художественное редактирование  посредственного текста и превращение его в шедевр?

Comment: "Можно предположить, что" можно заменить на "возможно" — так должно быть лучше. Редактировал под "может оказаться". Если так, то они просто боятся "спалиться", поскольку нет уверенности, что в помещении никого больше нет. Вам нужно под "оказалось"? *Спокойны, но напряжены* — разве это совместимо? "Находится" указывает на настоящее время. Вам важно сохранить оригинал (ориентировался на это)? Или нужна лишь передача оригинальной мысли, но высокохудожественно?

Comment: oleedd,  спасибо, над вашим ответом позже подумаю, а сейчас исчезаю.

Comment: Мне хотелось бы увидеть сам вариант художественного оформления текста, а не его анализ.  Остальное прочитайте в измененном вопросе.

Comment: Добавлены художественные варианты.

Comment: oleedd, сатира-юмор и всё такое. Тогда уж напишите шедевр в этом жанре, а то на первую премию пока не тянет.

Comment: Не понял. Надо же было показать волнение. Где сатира? Добавлен ещё один вариант.

Comment: Уже лучше... делаете успехи.   Все, конец связи. Остальное - на конкурс.

Comment: oleedd, где ваш окончательный конкурсный вариант (или два варианта)? Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой ответ. Там даны образцы.

Comment: Берите те, что вам больше нравятся. Пока новых нету.

Comment: Нету, так напишите.  Посмотрите возможные образцы в моем ответе. Нужно добавить контекст (для ясности) и обозначить время  событий.

Answer (score 1):

Если в форме объяснительной: «Поскольку в помещении оружейной не было света, там незамеченным оказался неизвестный третий, который и услышал наш разговор».

Ближе к первоисточнику: «В оружейной почти темно, и там незамеченным нами оказывается неизвестный, подслушивающий наш разговор».

Comment: Да, интересно. Объяснительная записка (1) и повествовательный рассказ о событиях (2).  Я бы еще местоимение "наш" убрала бы из варианта (2), без него лучше.

Comment: «Поскольку в помещении оружейной не было света» — тут нужно объяснить, почему его там не было: авария? Заодно следовало бы объяснить, зачем персонажей вообще понесло в оружейную без света. «В оружейной почти темно» — почему «почти»? Разговаривать можно и в полной темноте.

Answer (score 1):

> Время действия выглядит несогласованным.

Может быть, автор излагает события прошлого в настоящем времени — так делается. Картина могла быть такая: мы в тёмной кладовой разговариваем о своём, потом включаем свет/зажигаем фонарик (спичку, свечу) — и обнаруживаем, что всё это время нас подслушивал неизвестный!

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, свой вариант текста (рассказ о прошедших событиях или о происходящих сейчас)

Comment: Зачем я буду это писать? Мне от этого светит какая-то польза?

Comment: Светит, конечно. Если вопрос будет конкурсный, получите от меня премию. Также вас будут больше уважать, будут к вам прислушиваться.

Comment: Тогда я подумаю. Конкретнее о тексте, пожалуйста: вариантом чего мой текст должен быть? Сколько нужно предложений? И всё-таки: рассказ о прошедших событиях или о происходящих сейчас? Или это неважно? Но будущее время, значит, использовать запрещено? :)

Comment: Или вы всё-таки не собственного рассказа у меня просите, а моего варианта рассказа о случае в вышеупомянутой оружейной кладовой?

Comment: Ага, теперь понятно. Рассказов у вас два потому, что второй — в прошедшем времени? Соблазнительна также идея один текст написать стилем художественной прозы, а другой — в официальном стиле...

Comment: Да, все верно. Пишите!  Я учту все ваши достижения.

Comment: Кстати, надо учесть критику Александра. С чего это мы подозреваем неизвестного в том, что он подслушивает. Это только версия.

Comment: «А следователю мы скажем так: поскольку в оружейной кладовой окон нет, а свет мы не зажигали, то и не могли знать, что там находится ещё кто-то и весь наш разговор слышит».

Comment: «С чего это мы подозреваем неизвестного в том, что он подслушивает». — Так это же не мы: это действующее лицо шуганулось и заподозрило его.

Comment: Под протокол: «С целью обсудить этот вопрос частным порядком мы заходим в оружейную кладовую, где в тот момент никто не должен был находиться. Не желая ставить других в известность о нашем пребывании там, мы не пользуемся электрическим освещением. Поскольку в оружейной кладовой естественное освещение изначально отсутствует, нам не известно, что в данном помещении помимо нас находится некое третье лицо, подслушивающее наш разговор».

Comment: Мне нравится… Вариант принят.

Comment: *Поскольку... нам не известно* — как они могут об этом говорить, если им об этом не известно?

Answer (score 1):

Художественная правка без контекста невозможна, малопонятного фрагмента - тем более.
Чисто корректорской работы работы тут немного... Да, причастный оборот надо обособить, "помимо нас" - обособление факультативно, но я бы его сделал. Для корректора - это всё.

Единственное, что тут можно сделать редактору, не занимаясь домыслами и отсебятиной, так это изменить "поскольку"  в сочетании с "оказалось". Второе не следует из первого. И что автор имел в виду - непонятно. Какая связь затемненности с наличием ещё кого-то в комнате?

Если речь о том, что наблюдатель или герой повествования не сразу заметил этого дополнительного персонажа, то так и надо сказать. Я бы, появись у меня такая необходимость, изложил бы этот эпизод, максимально сохраняя авторский стиль.   Примерно так (в зависимости от деталей контекста - возможны варианты):

*«Поскольку помещение оружейной кладовой изначально ***было*** затемнено, ***только сейчас  выясняется (или в этот/такой-то момент выяснилось)***, что в комнате, помимо нас, находится неизвестное третье лицо,  подслушивающее ***(наш)*** разговор».*

"Лицо" - это, конечно, не для художественно стиля, но если автор таким образом передает особенности речи лирического героя-повествователя, то нехай останется.

Что касается временнЫх несогласовок, то я их здесь не вижу. Во всяком случае по одному предложению сказать ничего нельзя.

Вот простейший пример. *"Я вспомнил, как было дело. Мы разговариваем в помещении оружейной кладовой. Вдруг кто-то чихает поблизости. И только тогда я понял, что в помещении находится кто-то третий."*
Я специально нагромоздил смешение времен (обычно я так не делаю без особых на то причин), но вряд ли хороший редактор, не буквоед, придерется... Событийные моменты - в настоящем времени, воспоминания - в прошедшем. Это, типа, мой авторский стиль, я художник, я так вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Конкурсное задание как раз и состоит в том, чтобы додумать контекст и вписать в него исходное предложение (сохранив основное содержание, но изменив грамматику). Должна быть ясной коммуникативность текста – кто, кому и зачем это рассказывает.  Что касается согласования времен, то сейчас уже не об этом речь. Нужно просто правильно выбрать время, чтобы оно подходило к одному из вариантов:  изображение события в текущем времени или рассказ о совершившемся событии.

Comment: Я голосую за всех отвечающих, чтобы они находились в равных условиях. И обязательно буду учитывать другие голоса, чтобы выбрать лучший ответ. Мне хотелось бы, чтобы вы побыли писателем, а не корректором – так ведь интереснее.  Пожалуйста, представьте себя на месте Пушкина, Толстого или Достоевского. Как бы они описали этот эпизод?  Это же в какой-то мере игра, а не серьезная корректорская работа.

Comment: @Sharon *...на месте Пушкина, Толстого или Достоевского* - Нет, увольте. Я никогда не буду на их месте. В лучшем случае могу только спародировать. Но вы же не этого добиваетесь?

Comment: Мне все понравится, если будет оригинально и интересно.  Даже можно и предложение поменять. Только пусть в очень темной оружейной комнате происходят странные события :)

Comment: @Sharon *Как бы они описали этот эпизод?* - Вводная такая абсурдна. Я не вижу эпизода, одну фразу с туманным смыслом. Без контекста совершенно непонятно, о чем вообще речь. И ни один Пушкин не возьмется что-то тут описывать. Разве что импровизатор из "Египетских ночей". Но даже и ему давали вводную-тему, а не голую фразу фразу.

Comment: Я же написала образец...  Ну другие ответы были. А чем туманнее фраза, тем свободнее фантазия автора.

Comment: @Sharon *Мне все понравится, если будет оригинально и интересно* - Тогда вам надо задание по-другому сформулировать. Напишите, типа, рассказ, где есть такой эпизод. Это задание для литературной игры, когда-то я в таких участвовал и даже побеждал, но, простите, те времена давно в прошлом, сейчас я на такие подвиги не способен.)))

Comment: Не рассказ, а эпизод. Всего несколько предложений.  Вы попробуйте,  тем более что раньше писали.  А вдруг вам понравится и нам понравится... Честно говоря, меня мнение наших участников интересует больше, чем мое собственное.

Comment: *Не рассказ, а эпизод. Всего несколько предложений.* - Констатирую, что наш разговор зашел в полный тупик. Извините, но вы полностью игнорируете суть моих замечаний. Во-первых, ваш вопрос не так сформулирован. Меняйте как минимум заголовок.  Во-вторых, какая разница рассказ или эпизод, если никакого эпизода тут не просматривается. Есть не слишком грамотная фраза, суть которой непонятна без контекста. Естественно, при такой "вводной" ничего хорошего получиться не может. На этом все.  Еще раз простите.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания, я  исправила заголовок.

Answer (score 1):

Не отрывая взгляда друг от друга, бесшумно протискиваемся в приоткрытые двери тёмной оружейной и переходим на шёпот, нисколько не подозревая, что кто-то третий слышит нас (оказалось после, у неизвестного было намерение «слегка повеселиться», однако невинная эта затея принесла ему много пищи для серьёзных раздумий).

Comment: Давно не общались, *shampar*. Вечер добрый! Думается мне, что нужна запятая после "друг от друга".

Comment: Да, справедливо. Исправлю.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, интересный получился вариант.  Надеюсь, наши участники его оценят. Даже захотелось начало почитать, ну и что дальше было… :)

Answer (score 1):

Нам нужно было обсудить детали нашего тайного плана. В оружейной должно быть безопасно, там сто лет никто не бывал. Идем туда, свет не зажигаем и стараемся говорить тихо. И вдруг рядом раздаётся какой-то странный звук. Неужели кто-то заподозрил нас в измене и следил за нами? Но как он мог догадаться? Ведь он слышал всё… Что же нам теперь делать?

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за вариант, сюжет получился отличный,  и даже текущее время есть. Надеюсь, нашим участникам от тоже понравится.

Comment: Ответ обновлен.

Comment: Отлично, oleedd, стало еще лучше. Пожалуй, премия ваша!  Присуждается за интересное решение и внимание к теме на протяжении всего конкурса. А еще – за любовь к языку и активное участие в форуме.