# Не знаю, как быть со знаками препинания 

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, тире-или-двоеточие

Три предложения, в которых не уверен в правильности поставленных знаков (под вопросом те, что выделены скобками).

"И как я сказал чуть ранее(,) урок заключается в том, чтобы не поделиться, а полностью переложить всё возложенное на меня (–) лично тебе".

"Проверить на себе отцовское влияние я решил самым смешным способом (–) каждое утро, будто четырнадцатилетний, начал подбегать к зеркалу и высматривать(:) не стала ли расти борода".

"Я понимаю свою, вину (–) те нелепые поступки и страхи, заставлявшие тебя выполнять мои обязанности".

Comment: Вы сами пишете, да? Это интересно. В принципе у вас неплохой стиль, просто с одним предложением не все получилось. Выбранная форма настолько сложна, что даже содержание неясно, особенно без контекста. А то наши участники спорят о грамматике,  я же смысл до конца не понимаю. И как вы ставите знаки препинания, по правилам или по слуху (по интуиции)? И спрашиваете  только про правильность  постановки знаков или вас правила тоже интересуют?  Мы здесь все объясняем.

Comment: И еще. Хотите поучаствовать в конкурсе – правка заданного предложения. Было бы интересно увидеть ваш вариант. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467207/Всё-ли-верно-в-предложении-стилистика-пунктуация-грамотная-речь

Answer (score 0):

Под вопросом там отнюдь не только то, что в скобках :) Предлагаю варианты правки:

«И, как я сказал чуть ранее, урок заключается в том, чтобы не «поделиться», а полностью переложить всё, возложенное на меня — на тебя». (Интонационное тире по совместительству заменяет вторую запятую, закрывающую оборот.)

«Проверить на себе отцовское влияние я решил самым смешным способом: каждое утро я, будто четырнадцатилетний, начал подбегать к зеркалу и высматривать, не стала ли расти борода».

«Я понимаю свою вину — те нелепые поступки и страхи, заставлявшие тебя выполнять мои обязанности».

Праздное любопытство: это перевод?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128679/discussion-on-answer-by----------).

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант редактирования** первого предложения:

*И как я сказал чуть ранее, урок заключается в том, чтобы не поделиться, а полностью переложить на тебя всё то, что предназначено мне.*

В оригинале неясная семантика; грамматика и интонация также не очень хороши.

Второе предложение можно оставить: *Проверить на себе отцовское влияние я решил самым смешным способом – каждое утро, будто четырнадцатилетний, начал подбегать к зеркалу и высмАтривать: не стала ли расти борода?*

Такой вариант хорош в том случае, если вы хотите подчеркнуть вопросительную интонацию. Если же нет, то вам уже предложили оформление.

Comment: На ваш взгляд в этом варианте слишком много запятых?

"И, как я сказал чуть ранее, урок заключается в том, чтобы не «поделиться», а полностью переложить всё, возложенное на меня — на тебя".

Comment: Нет, дело не в знаках. Я обычно проверяю пунктуацию в предложениях с правильной грамматикой и структурой, с хорошей стилистикой. Здесь я прежде всего  не понимаю глагольное управление:  переложить что на кого, а у вас  переложить что кому. Тире непонятно зачем, слово "лично" кажется лишним. Я просто хотела содержание (как я его поняла) изложить по-другому.  Диагноз такой: плохо читается и понимается, хочется короче, выразительнее и яснее.

Comment: «В оригинале неясная семантика».  — Опять? :) Лично мне всё ясно и без переложения на стиль советского бюрократа. «Тире непонятно зачем». — «2. Тире, которое ставится между членами предложения для выражения неожиданности или для обозначения логического ударения, также имеет интонационный характер: И щуку бросили — в реку (Кр.)» — http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94 Диагноз Sharon: мало читает хорошей литературы и мало думает; нужно больше читать и думать, а не хотеть, чтобы остальные подстраивались под чужую умственную лень.

Comment: Егор, ничего не поняла - кто здесь ленивый и мало читающий? С  щукой все нормально, а вот с  этим предложением нет. Это я вам точно говорю :)

Comment: @Джин Запятая после И ставится, только если задумывается пауза.

Comment: @Sharon Вы не зря указали на проблемы с грамматикой. Она должна быть такой: *И как я сказал чуть ранее, урок заключается не в том, чтобы поделиться, а в том, чтобы полностью переложить всё возложенное на меня – на тебя.* Без контекста не понять, что имеется в виду.

Comment: Sharon, с предложением без щуки тоже всё нормально; ещё нормальнее бывает, но редко и не здесь — это я вам точно говорю :)

Comment: «Запятая после И ставится, только если задумывается пауза» — oleedd, нет: запятая после чего бы то ни было ставится только когда этого требуют или хотя бы это позволяют правила пунктуации.

Comment: Егор, а что там у нас с правилами? Мне кажется, в них сказано именно то, о чем говорит oleedd. Запятая здесь ставится в соответствии с паузой. Не согласны? Тогда дайте ссылку на правило (я могу дать).

Comment: @Sharon Под соседним ответом Егор говорит, что запятые никак не связаны с паузами. Вывод напрашивается сам: что с ним говорить?

Comment: Это ладно, он больше правилами увлекается, это его дело. Но здесь же правила какие – встреча присоединительного союза И с подчинительным союзом. КАК.  У Розенталя все подробно расписано: И, А обычно не обособляются, а НО обособляется по паузе.

Comment: Похоже на то, что он читал лишь долю правил (базовые), иначе бы не отстаивал глупости. Да там все по паузе, что нельзя делать уже в середине предложения.