# Есть ли у слова "дверь" взаимозаменяемый синоним?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, синонимы, тавтология

Встречали ли вы в художественной литературе случаи, когда у слова "дверь" был синоним? То есть порой это слово повторяется в нескольких предложениях подряд (дверь открылась — дверь закрылась), хочется чем-то заменить для избегания повторов, ан нет, вроде так не делают.

"Створка"? Двери бывают и одностворчатые, и двустворчатые, но если во втором случае бывает, что говорят, например, "правая створка закрылась", то в первом не встречал, чтобы обычную "дверь" заменяли на "створку".

"Полотно"? Это больше смахивает на технический термин: открывающаяся часть дверной конструкции; возможно, именно в художественной литературе это вряд ли применимо.

Что вы думаете, не коробит ли вас повтор слова "дверь" в одном или соседствующих предложениях?

Comment: *Shi*, спасибо за оценку ответа. Жаль, правда, что дверную тему, кроме меня, никто не поддержал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примеры с использованием слова "полотно":

*Я сделала несколько шагов и дотронулась **до двери**. Всего лишь дотронулась до неё, как старое **полотно** скрипнуло и легко открылось, являя мне просторную комнату и ту самую женщину с прошлой встречи* (Елена Болотонь. Заклятье старого зеркала);
*Наконец в-четвертых, первая же **дверь** в здание оказалась открытой. Стоило посильнее дернуть за ржавую ручку, как **полотно** скрипнуло и поддалось усилию, оторвав прибитую поперек палку* (Сергей Зверев. Бункер).

Если известна фактура двери, то всегда ее можно обыграть: ломятся в деревянную дверь — дерево трещало, стучат по металлической — железо гнулось, визжало, сопротивлялось.

А для ворот или старинных (массивных, высоких) дверей подходит устаревшее, солидное слово "створа":

*Загремела **створа**, скрипнула, ухнула, и все стихло бесследно* (Всеволод Иванов. Черные люди);
*А хозяин замка, прислонившись к **окованной створе**, только иногда вставлял пару слов и то ли хмурился, то ли улыбался (кто их разберет, этих аристократов?)* (из [моего ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467207/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0/467310#467310)).

Answer (score 2):

Я предпочитаю вообще не использовать одно и то же слово, включая местоимения, в пределах абзаца. И когда ты столь щепетильно относишься к собственным сочинениям, очень раздражает лень 99% авторов, у которых одно и то же существительное может встретиться до трёх раз в одном предложении (про "был", "стал", "видел" вообще молчу).

Безупречно подходящего синонима у слова "дверь" нет, но он может быть ситуационным и исходить из общей манеры авторской подачи. Невозможно дать универсальный алгоритм обхождения повторов. Тут и я сам к каждой задаче подхожу по-разному.

Могу лишь проиллюстрировать это примером из своих текстов:

> Вера обречённо протёрла ладошкой лицо и поняла — подъездную дверь не открыть. <...> Опять домофон? А, света же нет! Не заперто.

Здесь о двери можно было сказать дважды. Но второй раз слово опущено за счёт удачно подобранной формулировки во внутреннем монологе.

Конечно, это не ответ на ваш вопрос о синониме. Но думаю, подобные задачи решить можно и без него.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнение**

1. В некоторых случаях можно использовать как синонимы слова *полотнище* и *притвор*.

*Я ударяю ногой в древнюю **дверь** — втрое старше Уортропа — и деревянное **полотнище**, удовлетворенно крякнув, раскалывается по всей длине, а за моей спиной монстролог вскрикивает так жалобно, как будто это его я расколол пополам* (Р. Янси. Монстролог).

> <...> Именно ей принадлежала баня, с которой Антип сорвал **двери**.
> — Ну-ка, доставай **притвор**, сверчок кривоногий, — промолвила она тем голосом, каким произносят приговоры.
> — Хе-хе... — попятился Аптип. — Какой такой притвор? Дура, это по-культурному дверь называется, — пустился вдруг в поучение Антип, явно выгадывая время, чтоб обойти Кузьмину и улизнуть.
> А. Иванов. Тени исчезают в полдень

[[**Видеодополнение**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&oq=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5&aqs=chrome.0.0i355i512j46i512j69i57j0i512l2j46i512j0i512l4.4864j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:83ce8b4b,vid:03kj8o3hgb4) (14.02.23): 47–51 минуты.]

2. Еще примеры в поддержку литературности полотна.

*Взбегаю на второй этаж и, не останавливаясь ни на секунду, долблю в **дверь**. Колочу так, что **хлипкое полотно** ходит ходуном под моими руками* (Е. Орлова. Без тормозов).

*Эти **двери** не выбьешь и вдесятером, – сказал Ариэль, поднимая свечи выше и внимательно разглядывая **резное полотно** из тёмного дерева* (Н. Маслова. Хрустальное счастье).

*Почему-то **дверь** открыть у меня не получалось, **дощатое полотно** сопротивлялось моим попыткам, а когда я приложил чуть больше силы, просто вылетело из косяка вместе с петлями* (В. Лосев. Вой оборотня).